# How is the logging CLI implemented in substrate?

Tags: cli, log, logging

Often I've used the flags like `-lruntime=debug` or `-lparachain=debug` without really understanding how they work. I know that the `env_logger` crate allows you to specify which crates to emit log messages from like so: `RUST_LOG=my_app` but what about substrate/polkadot? Does it use `env_logger` or something else to enable crate level logging? Also, what significance does the string after the `-l` have? Does it specify, for instance, the crate named `parachain` in `-lparachain=debug`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-l` is essentially the same as `RUST_LOG`(which we also support BTW). You can pass the following values:

- One log level (`error`, `warn`, `info`, `debug`, `trace`) that applies to all targets.
- target=log level. The target is what you can specify as `target` to the logging macros or the crate name if you don't pass a `target`.

We are using `tracing` for logging which is a compatible `log` implementation.

Comment: Ah so `-l<target>` is equivalent to `RUST_LOG=target`. Strange I've never seen it mentioned before in either `log` or `env_logger` docs.

Comment: That is a substrate feature not any generic feature (the `-l`)